# A question on numerical approximation scheme for an integral and functions for which the scheme is exact

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

For $f \in C[0,1]$ and $n>1,$ let $T(f)=\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f(1)+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f(\frac{j}{n})]$ be an approximation of the integral $I(f)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.$ For which of the following functions $f$ is $T(f)=I(f)$ ?

1. $1+\sin 2\pi nx$
2. $1+\cos 2\pi nx$
3. $\sin^2 2\pi nx$
4. $\cos^2 2\pi (n+1)x$

**My attempt:** My first observation is that taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ in $T(f)$ gives the identity. So, we are mainly concerned in finding the functions $f$ for which the expression for $T(f)$ is true for all $n>1.$
Setting $n=2,$ I have eliminated the options 2), 3) and 4).
So, the answer is 1), which is correct as per the answer key.

But I do not want to solve this problem by eliminating the options. Rather I want a straight-forward solution as to why 1) is true for all $n>1$ and what property does 1) have that 2), 3) and 4) do not.
My intuition says that there must be some analytical method or some sort of a condition on $f$ so that $T(f)=I(f)$ is true. I am confused as how to obtain that condition, if at all there exists one.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question @Kakashi. I am able to see that the given scheme is that of the trapezoidal rule and that trapezoidal rule is exact for polynomials of degree upto 1. But, the given options are not polynomials. So, how does the fact that the given scheme is that of trapezoidal rule is helpful in the analysis. Please elaborate.

Comment: Asymptotic expansion of the error term is known for Trapezoid rule, so you can check the expansion for each integrand one by one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Periodic_and_peak_functions

Answer (score 0):

For any $n>1, f(x)=1+\sin 2 \pi nx, $ we have that $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and that $f(\frac{j}{n})=1+\sin 2 \pi n (\frac{j}{n})=1+ \sin 2 \pi j =1,$ for all $j=1,2,\dots,n-1.$

So, we have that $T(f)=\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{2}f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f(1)+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}f(\frac{j}{n})]=\frac{1}{n}[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+(n-1)\times 1]=\frac{1}{n}[1+n-1]=1.$

Also, we can easily see that $\int_{0}^{1} [1+ \sin  (2\pi nx)] dx =1.$

So, we have the equality for 1).

Comment: Is there any other shorter method to see why this works ?? Or is this the only way. Is there any connection between the given functions and the trapezoidal rule ? Please let me know.